# Finding control on aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, findcontrol

I have a Promote.aspx page which has  a few radcomboboxes; radTerm and radOldYear. Promote.aspx also has a radgrid which is updatable by a WebUserControl, promote.ascx. This Web user control has a  few radcomboboxes, radName and radNewyr.

In the promote.ascx.cs, i want to be able to find the comoboxes which are on the  promote.aspx. Tried using:

```
RadComboBox tl = (RadComboBox)this.Page.FindControl("radTerm");
```

in vain! Someone please help me find the controls on the main page. i am calling them thru the webusercontrol that i load in the radgrid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to find the promote.ascx control on the page, so:

```
Control promote = (Control)this.Page.FindControl("WhateverYouCalledPromote");
```

Now that you have found the control, you can search for the control that you want:

```
RadComboBox tl = (RadComboBox)promote.FindControl("radTerm");
```

Comment: The control tree on a page, is, well, a tree, all the controls are not linear, but are contained in controls that can be contained in other controls, etc..

Comment: RadComboBox tl = (RadComboBox)this.Page.Master.FindControl("WhateverYouCalledPromote").FindControl("radTerm");

Comment: Thanks abatishcev, your have helped me comeup with that! it worked!